# What is the appropriate JavaFX container to store labels in it?

Tags: javafx

What JavaFX container should I use to create something like the colored boxes below?

Each colored box needs to hold two labels, the title of the box and the numeric result of the conversion.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: setVisible(false)?

Comment: Visibility wouldn't be an issue. I was wondering what should I use to create those boxes.

Comment: Maybe an `HBox` or `VBox`? Look into JavaFX layouts...

Comment: I'm already using a FlowPane layout with Vertical orientation. Can I put multiple Vboxes inside a FlowPane?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I can't have a VBox inside a FlowPane layout.

Comment: "_I can't have a VBox inside a FlowPane layout_". You definitely can. The `children` list of **all** `Parent` nodes is an `ObservableList<Node>` which means all `Parent` nodes can have a child of any subtype of `Node`. That said, a `VBox` which holds other `VBox`es would probably work for you. If you end up needing many "sections" then look into using a `ListView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use VBoxes inside a FlowPane. Its obviously not exactly the same as your due to the fact that you did not post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but you get the idea.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
        flowPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50)");
        flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        flowPane.setVgap(20);

        flowPane.getChildren().add(new TextField("1"));

        VBox gramsVBox = new VBox();
        gramsVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Blue; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;");
        gramsVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Grams:"));
        gramsVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("453.000000001"));

        VBox kiloGramsVBox = new VBox();
        kiloGramsVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Green; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;");
        kiloGramsVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("KiloGrams:"));
        kiloGramsVBox.getChildren().add(new Label(".453000000001"));

        VBox ouncesVBox = new VBox();
        ouncesVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Red; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;");
        ouncesVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Ounces"));
        ouncesVBox.getChildren().add(new Label("16"));

        flowPane.getChildren().addAll(gramsVBox,kiloGramsVBox,ouncesVBox);

        Stage stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setHeight(220);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(flowPane));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Your time is appreciated. I suppose it would make more sense to create a class that has a calculate method attached to it and creates those cards (vboxes) to reduce repetition. Am I right?

Comment: Yes this was just to give you an idea of how to use vboxes inside a flowpane